# How do I print a custom menu?

Tags: theming

There are lot of tutorials on Internet about how to display menu, but no one works for me.
I have tried:

```
$menu_array = menu_navigation_links('menu_menu-login-menu');
print theme('links__menu_login_menu', array('links' => $menu_array));
```

```
print drupal_render(menu_tree_output(menu_tree_all_data('menu-login-menu')));
```

Both don't work.

My menu looks like this.

> [image]

Comment: By Default all the menus are available as block under Blocks section. You can assign it in to required region. Are you trying to do something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Menu Block module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) (D7)?

Disable the main menu in the theme settings and create one or multiple menu blocks with a lot of options for the menus. The module can render submenu items with the main navigation and/or in a separate menu-block. The Menu block module can render a custom menu as well.

You can also add an extra region to your theme that renders a menu-block-menu inside a nav-tag:

yourtheme.info file add:

```
regions[nav_custom] = Nav Custom
```

In page.tpl.php add:

```
<?php if ($page['nav_custom']): ?>
    <nav id="nav-custom" role="navigation" class="navigation">
      <?php print render($page['nav_custom']); ?>
    </nav> <!-- /.section, /#nav-custom -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: YES, thanks. I have already fixed this problem in the almost same way, you write here...